# What is wrong with this proxy.config : Angular 2

Tags: angular, reverse-proxy

I put together the following `proxy.config.json`:

```
{
  "/api/" {
    "target": "http://m.lowes.com/CatalogServices/product/nvalue/v1_0?nValue=4294857975&maxResults=6&showURL=1&rollUpVariants=1&showUrl=true&storeNumber=0595&priceFlag=rangeBalance&showMarketingBullets=1",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
   }
}
```

This just hits a backend available to grab a static list of products.

I'm running the following service to get this JSON:

```
getProductData(){
    return this.http.get('/api/')
}
```

I have a super straight forward subscriber to check the data:

```
this.productServ.getProductData().subscribe(
  ( data ) => {console.log( data)},
  (err) => console.log(err)
 );
}
```

my npm script is:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
```

yet I'm getting the following error:

```
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type:2
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/
_body: "<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL
"http&#58;&#47;&#47;&#37;5bNo&#37;20Host&#37;5d&#47;CatalogServices&#47;product&#47;nvalue&#47;v1&#95;0&#63;", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;1b7f1cb8&#46;1503983750&#46;cebb18
</BODY></HTML>
```

Additionally if I run a get in PostMan, I get the expected JSON. So I know the URL is good.

Followed the other proxy posts to the letter and still getting nowhere with this.  Tried messing around with some of it and didn't get far.  I have a feeling I'm doing something small but I'm just not seeing it.  Suggestions?

Edit:

I almost forgot to mention that I am getting the following in the console:

```
[HPM] GET /api/ -> http://m.lowes.com/CatalogServices/product/nvalue/v1_0?nValue=4294857975&maxResults=6&showURL=1&rollUpVariants=1&showUrl=true&storeNumber=0595&priceFlag=rangeBalance&showMarketingBul
lets=1
```

Am I to assume that this means I am finding the url?  If so, why am I getting this 400 error returned to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found most of the problem.  Here is the solution to resolving the 400 invalid url issue:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://m.lowes.com/CatalogServices/product/nvalue",
    "pathRewrite": {
       "^/api/":""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug",
    "headers": {"host": "http://www.localhost:4200"}
  }
}
```

Notice I removed the search parameters.  I added these as urlSearchParameters in the options of the http.

However this creates a new problem:

The URL requires that there be no trailing slash.  Whoever built this service didn't write anything to strip off a trailing slash, so it parses the boolean of 1 as 1/.  This tosses and error basically saying that it doesn't know what to do with this invalid option.

Is there a way to strip off this trailing slash?  This is occurring within the http call it would seem, as I am passing the parameters without a trailing slash.  Angular appears to be adding its own slash to the end. This is completely against my wishes.

**Anyone know how to strip the trailing slash from the url parameters when the http class decides to ship off my request?**